# Laravel make validation request not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request

When i submit the form is nothing happens.
here is my step.

php artisan make:request PostRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'=>['required','max:255'],
            'article'=>['required'],
            'image'=>['image']
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required'=>['need title'],
            'article.required'=>['need article'],
        ];
        
    }
}
?>
```

**App/Http/Controllers/PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\PostRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function store(PostRequest $request)
    {
        Post::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('post.index');
    }
}
?>
```

If i don't use PostRequest it work perfectly,like this.

**app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post=new Post;
        $post->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $post->title=$request->title;
        $post->article=$request->article;
        $post->image=$request->image;
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->route('post.index');
    }
```

And i missing something step?
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rules()` function has a return array.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'=>['required','max:255'],
        'article'=>['required'],
        'image'=>['image']
    ];
}
```

Change it to

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'=>'required|max:255',
        'article'=>'required',
        'image'=>'image'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Still not working.When i submit just clear the form and nothing happens.

Comment: You are one step closer now. Please add the following code in you form file to check for validation errors.


`@if($errors->has())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endif`